# The port is not recognized when working with esp32 in arduino ide 2.2.1 (windows 11 home edition)

Tags: arduino-ide, esp32

I'm trying to program the ESP32 board with Arduino IDE.
[image]
But The port it's not recogniized when working with esp32 in arduino ide 2.2.1.
After some research I found that the port is not recognized by my operating system (WINDOWS 11 home edition).
Image of Device Manager showing the message that the port is not recognized.

[image: Device Manager]

I installed the Silicon Labs drivers for the CP210x USB to UART Bridge.
After restarting the PC, the port is still not recognized.
I did a search with the command line and the driver CP210x USB to UART Bridge is not installed.
CMD Line image:
[image]

I'm out of ideas how to solve this problem, some one knows how to solve this issue?

Comment: please do not post a picture of text ... copy and paste the text instead ... format it as "code" so that it looks the same as on screen

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a Stack Account yet, but i saw this and i know the answer...

1. it appears by your photo that you do indeed have a CP2102 Chip which requires the driver from here
   [CP2102 DRIVER](https://www.silabs.com/developers/usb-to-uart-bridge-vcp-drivers?tab=downloads)

This driver should be able to be installed without connecting your ESP32 Dev Board.

2. This is a driver issue, so .. do this
   In Device Manager  (i'm going to make some assumptions because i don't know what motherboard you have or machine )  But....

- Uninstall the USB Drivers completely
- Re Install the USB Drivers
- Re Install the chipset drivers for your mainboard
- Ensure your BIOS is up to date, if not, Update it via the correct software.

After all that , Restart Your computer

- Try it again, if problem persists
- Open cmd.exe    Run  sfc/scannow    and press enter
  This will run the windows System File Checker
- Try again, If problem persists
- You likely have a knock off board, They are notorious for not wanting to play
  nice with the drivers.

it's also possible that your computer is faulty,  Try it on another computer, obviously
but at the end of the day , it's more likely that you have a knock off board or
you have a driver issue and things need to get updated and resolved.

Comment: I installed the drivers using legacy mode of the device manager. But the operating system trys to open the ESP32 as a simple usb. I'll try to uninstall the drivers, then I'll give the feedback.